# How to check all checkboxes in a checkboxlist when page first loads?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Seems simple enough, but I can't figure it out.  I've tried this code:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListDivision.Items)
            item.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

and this markup:

```
           <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListDivision" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDivisions" DataTextField="Divisions" DataValueField="Divisions" RepeatColumns="4">
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceDivisions" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:WebPortal_Call4HealthReports_ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="usp_HR_DivisionsSelectAll" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: `Listitem` is in the form tag? Your code works great the first time when you load the aspx page. But when you refresh or make a submit this code dosen't work anymore

Comment: No, ListItem is not in tag.  Yes, I want the event to only happen when the page is first loaded.

Comment: You say you tried that code. But you say you can't figure it out. What is not working with the code you've posted? You need to clearly describe exactly what the issue is.

Comment: Sorry I want says if CheckListBox is in the form tag not ListItem :S

Comment: The checkboxes in the CheckBoxListDivision control are not checked when the page is loaded.  They are all un-checked and they need to all by checked.

Comment: I added the aspx code to the question so you can see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it's not selecting the items is that Page_Load event is called before binding the CheckBoxList items. So in order to select all the items when page loads you have two options:

**First option:** Put the same code you're using in the **OnDataBound** event of the CheckBoxList.

Modify the CheckBoxList markup to this:

```
   <asp:CheckBoxList OnDataBound="CheckBoxListDivision_DataBound"
 ID="CheckBoxListDivision"  runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceDivisions" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" 
            RepeatColumns="4" >
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And add this in code-behind:

```
protected void CheckBoxListDivision_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       foreach (ListItem item in CheckBoxListDivision.Items)
       {
           item.Selected = true;
       }
   }
```

**Second option:** Remove the SqlDataSource from your markup and **bind the CheckBoxList programatically in Page_Load event**, then after binding the CheckBoxList, do the loop and you'll be able to select the items.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you Black Baron, I used the first option and it works perfectly.  It makes sense that ListItems will only exist **after** databinding.