# Pre-Check all boxes in a CheckBoxList

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am attempting to check all/specific checkboxes within a checkboxlist on pageload.

Currently there are no errors however even with Selected=true specified in the code behind, the checkboxes are displaying 'unticked'.

Here is my Code behind: (note: it is located within the Protected Void Page_Load and within if (!IsPostBack)

```
                    SqlConnection aircraftCheckConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CamoDatabaseString"].ToString());

                    SqlCommand aircraftCheckCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT [Type] FROM [AircraftType]");
                    aircraftCheckCommand.Connection = aircraftCheckConn;
                    aircraftCheckConn.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter aircraftCheckAdapt = new SqlDataAdapter(aircraftCheckCommand);
                    DataSet AircraftDS = new DataSet();
                    aircraftCheckAdapt.Fill(AircraftDS);
                    AircraftCheck.DataSource = AircraftDS;
                    AircraftCheck.DataTextField = "Type";
                    AircraftCheck.DataValueField = "Type";

                    aircraftCheckConn.Close();
                    AircraftCheck.DataBind();


                    foreach (ListItem li in AircraftCheck.Items)
                    {
                        li.Selected = true;

                    }
                    AircraftCheck.DataBind();
```

Here is my front-end

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="AircraftCheck" runat="server" DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="Type" CellSpacing="10" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" >
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based from [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), the `Page_Load` event called before binding of `CheckBoxList` items occur. You can replicate same code from `Page_Load` event in `CheckBoxList`'s `DataBound` event method and put `OnDataBound` handler on `CheckBoxList` markup to corresponding method:

**ASPX Markup**

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="AircraftCheck" runat="server" DataTextField="Type" DataValueField="Type" CellSpacing="10" RepeatColumns="6" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
OnDataBound="AircraftCheck_DataBound">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void AircraftCheck_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SqlConnection binding stuff here, omitted for brevity

    AircraftCheck.DataBind();

    foreach (ListItem li in AircraftCheck.Items)
    {
        li.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Similar issue:

[How to check all checkboxes in a checkboxlist when page first loads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23746797/how-to-check-all-checkboxes-in-a-checkboxlist-when-page-first-loads)

Comment: Initially this gave me a System.StackOverflow exception due to the presence of the AircraftCheck.DataBind() within the DataBound event. However once this was removed it functioned as desired. Thanks